# Use Build Packages When in Production Only

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-google-mobile-ads

Is there a way to use packages incompatible with Expo Go only when a specific environment variable is set?

I am trying to use `react-native-google-mobile-ads` however, I work on a Windows PC and cannot build using `expo prebuild` unless I switch to my Mac. I am wondering if I can use an environment variable to only use said package when wanted. I tried doing this:

```
// App.tsx
// inside App() and useEffect()

if (process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_BRANCH == "PRODUCTION") {
  mobileAds()
    .initialize()
    .finally(() => {
      setAdsLoaded(true);
    });
} else {
  setAdsLoaded(true);
}
```

However it still seems to throw the error `Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'RNGoogleMobileAdsModule' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native binary., js engine: hermes` I sort of expected this as it's still including the package and (I guess) typescript still compiles this code so needs the package either way.